# Gradient map effect in PHP, without additional packages?

Tags: php, image, colors, gradient

I know Imagemagick can achieve a "gradient map" effect by converting an image to greyscale, then creating an gradient and performing a Color Look Up Table transformation.

What I'm wondering is if PHP's default image functions can take a full colour image, and turn it into a duotone.

IMG_FILTER_COLORIZE would work if it allowed me to specify two colours!

Comment: The default image bits, based on the GD library, don't have this sort of automation built right in.  However, they can be easily used to create the effect entirely by hand...

Comment: Nice! I'm all for getting my hands dirty with some custom code, just have no idea where to start! Never worked with images before.

Comment: how dirty do you want to get your hands...? Specify exactly what you want and you can write it at the pixel level by doing your own color checking

Comment: Great question... trying to picture the problem... my first inclination would be to convert to greyscale... then for each pixel, see where it is between black and white. Then based on that percentage, select the appropriate value between my two specified colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one wanna get to the "Gradient Map" effect. The procedure is:

1. Make your image to grayscale... the easiest way is to use the model used for HDTV developed by the ATSC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale):

> Luma = 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B

2. Once you have your luma you gotta make a function to map luma from 0~100% to the gradient of color you want from 0%~100%... In other words:

> luma = 0% --> color A
>
> luma = 100% --> color B
>
> luma = X% --> interpolation between A and B ... InterpolatedColor = X% * B + ( 100 - X )% * A

Of course, apply these formula for all channels R, G and B.

This can be done in PHP easily once you have access to the pixels of the image.

Comment: It's posible to have more details about how to set the luma with code please ? Thanks :).

Comment: I fixed the last line that was actualy wrong. Tell me if you understand what must be done. I can't show it with actual PHP code because it depends on the structure you are using to represent pixels. This is a generic answer. Basically the PixelColor is an interpolation between 2 colors... the luma is the parameter (0 to 100%) of the interpolation.

Comment: For now I haven't any real structure. I just get a png from disk and want to add a gradient map effect on this one and save them on the disk. I think that I don't really understand is your/the concept of luma... Thanks for your help.

Comment: Luma = Luminance of the image. It's the function above dependent on Red, Green and Blue. The result is a value that represents the "grayscale version of the image". For every pixel (R,G,B), find the the luma and replace the pixel by (Luma,Luma,Luma) and then you will have the grayscale version of your picture. Remember, when R=G=B it's a grayscale color.